# Instantiate creates multiple (unwanted) copies of game object in scene root

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `GameObject.Instantiate()` method that create a `Page` game object. The `Page` game object then have a `Start()` method where it also instantiate some new game objects.

My issue is that the game objects that are created in the `Start()` method get created twice. First it get's created as children of the `Page` game object (which I want, that works correct), but then it also creates the same game objects in the root of the scene.

I've tried to add `Debug.Log("Calling start method...")` to `Start()` to see if the method gets called twice, however this does not seem to be the case. It does **not** output the text twice to the log.

### Navigation.cs

```
void navigateTo(Page page) {
    ...
    // Here we instantiate the Page.
    this.currentPage = GameObject.Instantiate (page.gameObject, this.content.transform).GetComponent<Page>();
}
```

### Page.cs

```
void Start () {
    // Here we create a child GameObject. This get's created both as a child of 
    // the Page game object, but also in the root of the scene.
    GameObject tableGO = new GameObject ("Table");
    GameObject instance = GameObject.Instantiate(tableGO, this.gameObject.transform) as GameObject;
    ...
}
```

Comment: yoy are setting your parent in the instantiate call... the root copy is done in another place or script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `new GameObject ("Table")` creates a gameObject which is without parent and `GameObject.Instantiate(tableGO, this.gameObject.transform) as GameObject;` also creates a gameObject but in the second case you use the first gameobject as a template (or like prefab) and set a parent to it. So you can remove `GameObject tableGO = new GameObject ("Table");` and use prefab to create gameobject or remove the second line and set `tableGO.transform.parent` to whatever you need.

Comment: Oh, I guess I got confused by the method name `Instantiate`. I expected it to be used to instantiate game objects to the scene, just like it does with prefabs. Therefore I expected `new GameObject()` to just keep it in memory and not add it to the scene yet.

Comment: @MarcusLind yes, it's rather confusing that both gameobject ctor and Instantiate do similar things. But ctor is rarely used because instantiate method gives more opportunities (set parent and etc)